# How can I ensure continuity of Time Machine history from Yosemite to El Capitan?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I know this is a notoriously difficult problem to solve on OS X, but I'll try again, circa El Capitan era.

I have used the disk shown below as Time Machine disk with Yosemite.

[image: time-machine-disk]

Yet when I select it as Time Machine disk now that I upgraded to El Capitan, it is accepted as a backup disk, but not as an existing disk. Hence there will be no continuity in the history (and the oldest backups will be erased sooner than necessary).

How do I have continuity?

My attempt to make sure that the name of the machine (under system preferences \ Sharing) exactly matches the previous name of the machine does not solve the problem.

Comment: Is it a straight upgrade, or did you clean install?

Comment: It's a little bit of both. I did a clean install. Then I used migration assistant to move the files (I only backup user files, not system files) to the newly installed OS X. You would think that this by itself would trigger the "this Time Machine disk should continue backing up incrementally from where it left off" flag.